# Using Angular Router to load a component within a component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I'm using the Ionic frame work (v5) and implementing Angular Router to load an app with the following structure.

App

```
 - Tabs
 -- Tab 1
 -- Tab 2
 -- Tab 3
```

This is a boilerplate template that you can choose to have Ionic setup for you. So this navigation is working correctly using the Angular Router setup below.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy } //     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

tabs.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

tabs-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

What I'm trying to do is introduce a secondary menu within each tab that uses a navigation system similar to Material Tabs https://material.io/components/tabs#. Each tab would load inline a different component. So Tab 1 would remain active and continue to allow the user to tab between section 1, 2 or 3.

App

```
 - Tabs
 -- Tab 1
 --- Section 1
 --- Section 2
 --- Section 3
 -- Tab 2
 --- Section 1
 --- Section 2
 --- Section 3
 -- Tab 3
 --- Section 1
 --- Section 2
 --- Section 3
```

This is what I have so far for

tab1.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }]),
    MaterialModule,
    Tab1PageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```

tab1-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tab1',
    component: Tab1Page,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'section1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
            import('../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule)
          }
        ]             
      },
      {
        path: 'section2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
            import('../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule)
          }
        ]     
      },
      {
        path: 'section3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
            import('../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule)
          }
        ]     
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1/section1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1/section1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Tab1PageRoutingModule {}
```

But when I try to navigate to /section1 from the /tabs/tab1 route it presents the error message

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'section1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `tab1` route in tabs-routing.module.ts and in tab1-routing.module.ts you're again declaring a `tab1` route with a `section1` children. So right now what you really have is `tabs/tab1/tab1/section1`. Then in tab1-routing.module.ts you are redirecting from `''` to `/tabs/tab1/section1` which doesn't exists. You need to change the `''` route redirect in tab1-routing.module.ts to:

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1/tab1/section1',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Also note that in tab1.module.ts you are importing two router modules. That could led to some weird results.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }]), //<- here
    MaterialModule,
    Tab1PageRoutingModule // <- and here
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```

Comment: My goal is to have the route be /tabs/tab1/section1. What alterations to the tab1-routing.module.ts do I need to make to achieve that?

Comment: This ended up getting me there. I just removed the path 'tab1' from the tab1-routing.module.ts and everything is working! Thank you.